# Al usar en Styles.xml el tema parent de android:Theme.Material.Light la app no funciona

Tags: java, android, material-design

Simplemente al abrir una app nueva (empty activity) "Hello World" y cambiar el tema de

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

a

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">`

El móvil me dice. Desafortunadamente, la app se ha detenido. 
Mi móvil tiene android 6 y en el emulador tampoco funciona. 
Si dejo la opción original la ActionBar no me cambia de color cuando se lo asigno. 
Mil grácias.

Añado el Logcat:(es esto)

> 05-20 20:03:18.684 20230-20230/com.example.hector.materialdesign E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.hector.materialdesign, PID: 20230
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hector.materialdesign/com.example.hector.materialdesign.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                                          at com.example.hector.materialdesign.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
>   05-20 20:04:30.801 20230-20236/com.example.hector.materialdesign W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.267ms
>   05-20 20:08:19.131 20230-20230/com.example.hector.materialdesign I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20230 SIG: 9

Y el Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hector.materialdesign"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Jorgesys te voy a mencionar en los agradecimientos de mi TFG me has ayudado en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Agrega lo que despliega en el LogCat y tu build.gradle

Comment: @Jorgesys ya lo he añadido. Espero que te refirieras a eso, no lo tenía muy claro.

Comment: Hola gracias por agregar mas detalles, aùn no tienes el problema?

Comment: Aun no consigo que funcione. Si uso un  Theme.AppCompat podre usar los cardview y todo lo demas que ofrece material design ?

Comment: te recomiendo usar el tema de compatibilidad <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este Tema :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
```

**requiere como minimo API 21**

El problema es :

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity.

ya que estas usando una clase de compatibilidad, que es AppCompatActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Si cambias a

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

podrá funcionar sin problema pero te aconsejo usar la clase de compatibilidad y un Tema de compatibilidad que sería

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```